# Is vector<bool> violating container requirements?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

C++ standard draft [n3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) in 23.2, in table containing container requirements, states that `X::reference` for container containing `T` must be `lvalue T`. Yet, for `vector<bool>`, `vector<bool>::reference` is another class, a proxy for accessing individual bits of bytes stored in vector.

Does that mean that `std::vector` class template specification for `T = bool`, defined in standard, fails to fulfill container requirements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does that mean that `std::vector` class template specification for `T = bool`, defined in standard, fails to fulfill container requirements?

Yes.

Similarly, its iterators are not truly random access iterators, because `operator*` yields a proxy object.

`vector<bool>` is a mess.

Comment: Not really a mess; it's handy, and it works. You do have to be careful in generic code that deals with vectors, though.

Comment: It would have been better not to have specialized `vector`, though, and instead to have defined an entirely new type.  Hindsight is 20/20.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, as stated [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/050.htm) with a nice explanation.

Comment: Well, with a one-sided explanation. <g> He didn't win that battle.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `vector<bool>` does not meet the container requirements. It doesn't claim to, although there is a fairly clear implication. The thing is, the container "requirements" aren't requirements in any formal sense; there is nothing in the standard library that requires a type that meets the container requirements. Rather, the "requirements" are descriptive: each container's documentation can say (as does the documentation for `vector<bool>`) "this container meets the container requirements, except ...".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it do. First, it uses proxy object `vector <bool>::reference` which is not actually a reference, but only looks same(its a class). Second, it have **flip()** method that other vectors does not have. Also, it does not support converting to C-like array unlike all other vectors: `&vec[0]`.

So, actually **vector< bool>** is not a vector but looks like vector and its data is not a **bool** but look like **bool**. This container is worldwide considered as "standardized but failed thing".

Comment: Um, no, it's not worldwide considered as failed.