# Dereferenced iterator returning a different iterator type by value

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a Matrix class with 2 iterator classes:

```
class Matrix{
 public:

  // matrix functionality...

  class RowVecIterator {
   public:

    using value_type = int; 
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t; 
    using reference = int&; 
    using pointer = int*;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    RowVecIterator(Matrix& mat, int row, int col);

    RowVecIterator& operator++();
    RowVecIterator operator++(int);

    reference operator*(); // THIS IS CORRECT IAW ISO C++ STD

    RowVecIterator begin();
    RowVecIterator end();

    // friends  

   private:
    // members
  };
   
  class RowIterator {
   public:
  
    using value_type = RowVecIterator;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t; 
    using reference = RowIterator&;
    using pointer = RowIterator*;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
 
    RowIterator(Matrix& mat, int row);                                                                                                                                                                  

    RowIterator& operator++();
    RowIterator operator++(int);

    value_type operator*() {                // QUESTION EXISTS HERE
      return RowVecIterator(mat, row, col); // RETURNS VALUE_TYPE AS NEW/DIFFERENT ITERATOR
    }                                       // SHOULD BE A REFERENCE

    // friends   

   private:
    // members
  };
};
```

The matrix holds a 1D vector that gets passed to the iterators. The RowIterator advances through the matrix's rows. When a RowIterator is dereferenced, it returns a value_type of RowVecIterator that is used to advance through elements in that row.

However, with dereferencing the RowIterator, it is not per the ISO C++17 std. Or is my understanding incorrect and it's okay to return a RowVecIterator by value? Otherwise, how can I solve this without changing the underlying data structure to a 2D/3D vector.

Thanks!

Comment: This also what `vector<bool>` does https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool/reference

Comment: Bad example because std::vector<bool> is not a real container. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678236/is-vectorbool-violating-container-requirements